# when i try to import facebook prophet: pip install fbprophet ... i alway get this error

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpstan<4.5,>=4.4 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet) (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.2.3, 0.2.5, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.1, 1.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpstan<4.5,>=4.4 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem trying to install PyStan at Windows 10 and found here (https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html#notable-changes) that last version PyStan (version 3) aren't available for windows anymore. Just for Linux and MacOS. I'll create a Linux Docker to solve it.

I found it too (https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/17#issuecomment-808769442) explaining the team are working at new release to solve another problem from PyStan 3.

Hope it help you too.

Answer (score 0):

What I found to install Prophet on Windows 10 machine was to install Anaconda and then with a terminal with Adminstration rights run the following commands

1. conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
2. Pip install prophet

Important step is to use the conda environment to run the python file

I want to ack: the youtuber Geek Mohit for posting this solution on youtube :)